# $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_0^1 f(\epsilon g(x)) dx=0?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ is continuous and strictly increasing with $f(0)=0$, $g:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}_+$ is continuous and decreasing such that  $g(1)=0$ and $\int_0^1 f(g(x)) \textrm{d}x$ exists. Do these imply  $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_0^1 f(\epsilon g(x))\textrm{d}x=0$?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? What do you think the answer is? Etc., share your thoughts

Comment: Think about why we require $\int f(g(x)) dx$ to exist, and then you might think of a particular theorem

Comment: @FShrike the challenge is when $\lim_{x\to0} g(x)=\infty$. Otherwise the problem is trivial. I don't see how to handle this case

Comment: $0\le f(\epsilon g(x))\le f(g(x))$ for $0<\epsilon<1$. The observation that $g$ decreases is irrelevant. It only matters that $g\ge0$

Comment: @Fshrike $0 < 1/(\epsilon^2) < 2/(\epsilon^2)$ for $0<\epsilon<1$. But this doesn't imply the integral equals $0$, at least I don't see this immediately.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of your comment. And no, it's not immediate. I'm thinking about the dominated (or monotone) convergence theorem

Comment: The fact that (())≤(()) implies $\int_0^1 f(\epsilon g(x)) dx$ is bounded. But for any fixed $\epsilon$, $f(\epsilon g(x))$ can approach infinity as $x\to 0$.  So I don't see yet how the former fact is directly useful.

Comment: @FShrike I see now, that should solve the problem. Thanks.